# Merge two feature layers that include photos in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, attachments, arcgis-survey123

I have 3 users in ArcGIS Online that students were using to collect data via Survey123 app throught a smiliar survey. They mapped points in a certain area including a photo for each point.  In each user there's a point layer with photo attached to each point. I want to merge all the 3  feature layers from the 3 users to one layer with the photos in my ArcGIS Online user. 
I tried to download the layers to my computer as shapefiles and than upload them to my user and merge. This option is working, just the photos got lost in the new layer.

How can I merge the 3 layers to one layer with the original photos taken?

Comment: Use Pro, merge (data management) command, maintain attachments environment setting = True

Comment: You will lose the attachment relationship when exporting by shapefile. You need to export to GDB to maintain the attachments.

Comment: Is there any option to do so without using Pro?